# .htaccess - Redirect all .html capture the ID

Tags: .htaccess, laravel-5

I am facing the following problem:

I have a website in which the URLS currently look like:

```
/manufacturer/product/[ID].html
```

I have re-developed the website (Using Laravel) and now it just is:

```
/product/[ID]
```

I am wondering whether it is possible to use a .htaccess file to redirect all these links back to the new link? So, in essence, I would need to just capture the [ID] from the old link and redirect it back to the new link.

EDIT:

So the link will look something like this:

```
mysite.com/parts/apple/A-6-H0.htm
```

OR

```
mysite.com/microsoft/A-1-5F.htm
```

So both `Apple`, `Microsoft` and `A-` can change depending on what manufacturer and what the product is Does this make sense?

Comment: Is your htaccess inside /manufacture folder?

Comment: @starkeen No, this is a laravel project the .htaccess file is inside /public

Comment: And where should `mysite.com/parts/apple/A-6-H0.htm` redirect to?

Comment: @hjpotter92 - Just back `mysite.com/parts/A-6-H0/`

Comment: @hjpotter92 Does this now make sense?

Comment: @hjpotter92 Sorry, did you see my previous comment?

Comment: @Phorce I've updated my reply below. Sorry for the delay.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^parts/(?:[^/]+/)?(.*)\.html?$ /parts/$1/ [R=301,L]
```

That should take care of it.

Comment: It's not working as there is a `/manufacturer` in the way.. I need to ignore this.. Currently it will redirect from: `/manufacturer/product/[ID].htm` to: `/manufacturer/product/[ID]` so it kind of works

Comment: @Phorce If the `manufacturer` is always present (followed by product), the above code shall redirect you to `/product/ID` page, and removes the manufacturer too! =)

Comment: So sorry about this. The link would be: /manufacturer/product/[ID].htm - but the manufacturer could be ANYTHING so like apple, microsoft so I want to completely remove this..

Comment: Sorry, it will be like this: `/product/[MANUFACTURER]/[PRODUCT_ID]` - Can i do this? I need the [MANUFACTURER] and [PRODUCT_ID] to be removed and redirect to just `/`

Comment: @Phorce Can you edit your question, and put a few "actual" links and the final redirection links?

Answer (score 1):

Please Try this:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^{domain name}[nc]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ {domain name}/$1 [r=301,nc]   
Redirect 301 /manufacturer/product/$1.html product/$1.html
```

Comment: @mayank - Also, it's not going to be always /manufacturer/ `/manufacturer/` is a variable.. It could be Apple, Microsoft etc..